# MSFakes Naming Convention to match Generic class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, microsoft-fakes

I have a class called `MyClass`, and a generic version called `MyClass<C>`.  Using fakes, I want to generate a shim of JUST `MyClass<C>`, and not `MyClass`.  I originally tried:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="XXXX" Version="#.##.###"/>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="MyClass!"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

This generated shims for `MyClass`, but not `MyClass<C>`.  If I change the ! to a *, it does match `MyClass<C>`.  This leads me to believe there is some naming convention I need to use to match `MyClass<C>`.  Does anyone know what it is/where I could find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the grave accent character plus the number of generic type parameters on the type. For example: `MyClass<T>` would be 1, `MyClass<T,U>` would be 2, etc. See also CLI [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) *Section 10.7.2 Type names and arity coding*.

You should also add your namespace as a part of the value.

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="XXXX" Version="#.##.###"/>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="MyNamespace.MyClass`1!"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Comment: Great point on the namespace.  I do have that, but I stripped it out to hastily ask this question.