# How to make MS Fakes generate shims for generic collection types like List<T>?

Tags: generics, microsoft-fakes

In Visual Studio 2017, when I generate fakes for System assembly, no shims are generated for generic collection types like e.g. List or Dictionary.

Setting Diagnostics attribute to "true" in Fakes xml didn't produce any helpful message on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: [MSFakes Naming Convention to match Generic class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434672/msfakes-naming-convention-to-match-generic-class) .  The answer to that question shows how to edit a fakes file to specify the number of expected generic arguments.  Be sure to rebuild your project to see the effects of the changes to the fakes file.